# convert inner xml to powershell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, xpath, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to create a dictionary using PowerShell. Following is the xml file,

and I'm working on following code,

```
$env = "Test"
$myDictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$xmlfile = [xml] (Get-Content "file-name")  
$xmlfile.SelectNodes("descendant::configuration/environment[@id='$($env)']/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]") | ? Value | % { $myDictionary.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value)  }
```

I want my output as follows,

```
Key            Value
----            -----
smtpserver      smtp1.org
type            test
encryption     <add key ="DB1" value="mhu0VrvzBBlYjPbxh+EQk0zdY"/>
               <add key ="DB2" value="DVvHAq2EVKF5fmYYiUUJ/g=="/>
               <add key="DB3" value="dkcdowefnwlwkli/" />
```

I want to include the inner xml part in the dictionary. Can someone suggest a possible solutions for the above requirement ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the following XPath, which will return *all direct child elements* of the matched `<environment>` :

```
//configuration/environment[@id='target_id_here']/*
```

And then use `$myDictionary.Add($_.ToString(), $_.InnerXml)` to add each element's *name and inner XML pair* to the dictionary.

---

**Demo :**

```
PS C:\Users\har07> $xml = [xml]@"
>> <configuration>
>>   <environment id="Test">
>>     <smtpserver>smtp1.org</smtpserver>
>>     <type>test</type>
>>     <encryptioninfo>
>>       <add key ="DB1" value="mhu0VrvzBBlYjPbxh+EQk0zdY"/>
>>       <add key ="DB2" value="DVvHAq2EVKF5fmYYiUUJ/g=="/>
>>       <add key="DB3" value="dkcdowefnwlwkli/" />
>>     </encryptioninfo>
>>   </environment>
>> </configuration>
>> "@
PS C:\Users\har07> $env = "Test"
PS C:\Users\har07> $myDictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
PS C:\Users\har07> $xml.SelectNodes("//configuration/environment[@id='$($env)']/*") | % { $myDictionary.Add($_.ToString(), $_.InnerXml)  }
PS C:\Users\har07> $myDictionary

Key            Value
---            -----
smtpserver     smtp1.org
type           test
encryptioninfo <add key="DB1" value="mhu0VrvzBBlYjPbxh+EQk0zdY" /><add key="DB2" value="DVvHAq2EVKF5fmYYiUUJ/g==" />...
```